# How to create paginate with variable passed by session

Tags: php, laravel, session, elasticsearch, pagination

I'm using this [package](https://github.com/basemkhirat/elasticsearch) to do research with Elastic Search in Laravel 5.4.

I have a screen for the user to fulfill the search requirements. With this method I am verifying which fields have been filled and I create the query that will search in the ES.

```
public function search(Request $request)
{   
    $searchParams = ['vehicle', 'year_min', 'year_max', 'mileage_min', 'mileage_max', 'exchange', 'keyword', 'optionals', 'phone', 'daterange'];
    $query = ES::type("ads");

    foreach($searchParams as $param) {

        if($request->has($param)) {

            if($param == 'vehicle') {
                $results = $query->where("vehicle", "like", $request->vehicle);
            }

            if($param == 'keyword') {
                $results = $query->where("description", "like", $request->keyword);
            }

            if($param == 'year_min') {
                $results = $query->where("year", ">=", intval($request->year_min));
            }

            if($param == 'year_max') {
                $results = $query->where("year", "<=", intval($request->year_max));
            }

            if($param == 'mileage_min') {
                $results = $query->where("mileage", ">=", intval($request->mileage_min));
            }

            if($param == 'mileage_max') {
                $results = $query->where("mileage", "<=", intval($request->mileage_max));
            }

            if($param == 'exchange') {
                $results = $query->where("exchange", "like", $request->exchange);
            }

            if($param == 'optionals') {
                $results = $query->where("optionals", "like", serialize($request->optionals));
            }

            if($param == 'phone') {
                $results = $query->where("phone", "exists", true);
            }

        }
    }

    $all_leads = $results->orderBy("created_at", "desc")->paginate(15);
    $all_leads->setPath('/dashboard/crawler/resultados');

    Session::put('all_leads', $all_leads);
    return redirect()->action('DashboardAdmin\ProspectingLeadController@results');
}
```

After mounting the query I am calling another method to render the results and passing the array by session.

```
$all_leads = $results->orderBy("created_at", "desc")->paginate(15);
$all_leads->setPath('/dashboard/crawler/resultados');

Session::put('all_leads', $all_leads);
return redirect()->action('DashboardAdmin\ProspectingLeadController@results');
```

When I search the results by the session and send to the view the paginate does not work lists only the results of the first page and if I click the paging buttons it changes the URL but does not change the records.

```
public function results()
{
    $all_leads = Session::get('all_leads');
   return view('dashboard_admin.prospecting_lead.index', compact('all_leads'));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the result method, you are getting the result from the cache, and therefore the paginator does not work. It will simply get those 15 results each time. For the paginator to work you need to call the paginator so it can fetch the results based on the querystring.